# Rails:can I set a fixed value in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to do something like

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |book_form| %>
<%= book_form.select{:author_id, [id] %>
...
<% end %>
```

in a view without showing up the select-box (since there is no alternative).
In other words: Can I set a value inside a form without showing anything on the view?

Ah, I see: hidden_field works, but with a slightly different syntax:

```
<%= book_form.hidden_field :author_id, :value => id %>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do want to never show the field? If so, you can do `<%= book_form.hidden_field :author_id, id %>`. Or do you only want to not show it if there is only one option?

Comment: you mean a hidden field?

Comment: I want to never show the field. With the hidden_field I get an error     undefined method `merge' for 9:Fixnum   where 9 is the id.

Comment: try this book_form.hidden_field :author_id, value: id

Comment: in future, in case of similar problems, remember that apidock is here to help you :) http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Comment: Difficult to use if you don't know what you are looking for.